# Is it possible to make a Picasa album to not appear in native Gallery application?

Tags: gallery, picasa

By default, it synchronizes every Picasa album you have in your Google account, even the marked as private ones.

I'd like to make some of them to not be imported on my phone.

Comment: Is this the Cooliris Gallery (http://www.cooliris.com/mobile/nexus-one/)? I don't think this comes as standard with Android.

Comment: Yes, it is. It came with my 2.1 Motorola Milestone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible at this time. This [answer in the Google support forums](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/android/thread?tid=1184f5182a166cdb&hl=en) indicates that it can't be done, but that it will be forwarded on as a feature request.